# Compare two columns from which one column is not mandatory

Tags: excel, vba, loops, office365, comparison

I need help for a macro code.

In my case the excel macro checks data in one sheet ("Check_file") for completeness and correctness.
There are mandatory columns in the sheet which have to exist and also not-mandatory columns can exist.

In my example the columns “company” and “fee” are mandatory columns, if they are missing or false the macro will throw an error.
Next to them, the column “gross fee” is not-mandatory and its data should only be checked with the data in column “fee”, if column “gross fee” exists. If it exists, the amount should be the same as in column “fee”. If it doesnt exist, there should be no comparison.

The check for the mandatory columns works fine within a For-Loop and an own Range.

My problem is that I dont know how I can involve the not-mandatory columns into the loop of the mandatory columns…
I tried to define a separate Range for the not-mandatory columns area. But it seems that I cannnot create the connection to the not-mandatory column if it is not set in the mandatory columns loop. But if it is set to the mandatory columns range and the not-mandatory column doesnt exist, an error will be thrown.

Should the exist-check for the not-mandatory columns be placed in a separate Sub or Function? If yes, how can the connection be created to the mandatory check Range?

This is the vba code:

```
Function Main_Check(ByVal StrFilePath As String) As String
    '//Checks all criteria for the correct filling of the template. Marks all fields that are incorrectly 
    filled in red.

    Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, iNotMand As Long, lEnde As Long, strHeader As String, ii As Long, lColEnde As Long
    Dim rngFind As Range, booCheck As Boolean, rngHeader As Range, rngKey As Range, rngUsed As Range,
    rngHeaderNotMand As Range, rngFindNotMand As Range, rngKeyGrossFee As Range, rngGrossFee As Range
    Dim strKey As String, arrKey As String, strKeyGrossFee As String, strGrossFee As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If StrFilePath = “” Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    '//Template is opened
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(StrFilePath)
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets(“Check_file”)

    With WS
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    '//Stores the last row and column to be processed
    lEnde = .Cells(.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 2, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lColEnde = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column


    '//Find the beginning of the table
    Set rngFind = .Cells.Find(what:=Settings.Cells(Settings.Range("Header_Start").Row + 1, 2).Value,
    LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If rngFind Is Nothing Then
         booCheck = False
    End
    End If

    .Range(rngFind.Address, .Cells(.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row,
    rngFind.Column)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

    lEnde = .Cells(.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 2, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    '//booCheck is set to true and on error to false _
    Thus, if "True" is passed, the complete file is correct

    Set rngUsed = .Range(rngFind.Address, .Cells(lEnde, lColEnde))

    booCheck = IsErrorAll(rngUsed)
        
    '//Header Check _
    Checks all headers in advance to see if they are present and writes the missing ones in a cell
    .Cells(4, 7).Clear
    .Cells(4, 8).Clear
     For i = Settings.Range("Header_Start").Row + 1 To Settings.Range("Header_Ende").Row - 1
    Set rngHeader = .Range(rngFind, .Cells(rngFind.Row, lColEnde)).Find(what:=Settings.Cells(i, 2).Value,
    LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If rngHeader Is Nothing Then
             booCheck = False
        
             .Cells(4, 7).Value = "The following column labels were not found: "
        
             If .Cells(4, 8).Value = "" Then
                  .Cells(4, 8).Value = .Cells(4, 8).Value & Settings.Cells(i, 2).Value
             Else
                  .Cells(4, 8).Value = "," & .Cells(4, 8).Value & Settings.Cells(i, 2).Value
             End If
             .Cells(4, 8).Interior.Color = vbRed
        
         Else
        
         End If
    
Next i

    If booCheck = False Then GoTo Ende

    '// Check Not-Mandatory Columns _
     Checks in advance whether Not-mandatory columns are available
    Set rngFindNotMand = .Cells.Find(what:=Settings.Cells(Settings.Range("NotMand_Start").Row + 1, 2).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
For iNotMand = Settings.Range("NotMand_Start").Row + 1 To Settings.Range("NotMand_Ende").Row - 1
Set rngHeaderNotMand = .Range(rngFindNotMand, .Cells(rngFindNotMand.Row, lColEnde)).Find(what:=Settings.Cells(iNotMand, 2).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not rngHeaderNotMand Is Nothing Then
    '//Not-mandatory columns are defined
     strKeyGrossFee = "Gross fee"
     Set rngKeyGrossFee = Settings.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Find(what:=strKeyGrossFee, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
     strGrossFee = Settings.Cells(rngKeyGrossFee.Row, 2).Value
    Else
    strKeyGrossFee = ""
    End If

'//All line items are run through and the individual criteria are checked
For i = rngFind.Row + 1 To lEnde Step 1
    
    '//Company
    strKey = "Company"
    Set rngKey = Settings.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Find(what:=strKey, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    strHeader = Settings.Cells(rngKey.Row, 2).Value
    Set rngHeader = .Range(rngFind, .Cells(rngFind.Row, lColEnde)).Find(what:=strHeader, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    iCoi = rngHeader.Column
    If .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Value Like "####" Then
        .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    Else
        .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed
        booCheck = False
    End If
    
    '//Fee
    strKey = "Fee"
    Set rngKey = Settings.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Find(what:=strKey, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    strHeader = Settings.Cells(rngKey.Row, 2).Value
    Set rngHeader = .Range(rngFind, .Cells(rngFind.Row, lColEnde)).Find(what:=strHeader, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Value Like "*,*" Then
             .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed
              booCheck = False
    Else
        .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
            
    '//Gross fee
    strKey = "Fee"
    Set rngKey = Settings.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Find(what:=strKey, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    strHeader = Settings.Cells(rngKey.Row, 2).Value
    Set rngHeader = .Range(rngFind, .Cells(rngFind.Row, lColEnde)).Find(what:=strHeader, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    Set rngFindNotMand = .Cells.Find(what:=Settings.Cells(Settings.Range("NotMand_Start").Row + 1, 2).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    strKeyGrossFee = "Gross fee"
    Set rngKeyGrossFee = Settings.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Find(what:=strKeyGrossFee, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    strGrossFee = Settings.Cells(rngKeyGrossFee.Row, 2).Value
    Set rngGrossFee = .Range(rngFindNotMand, .Cells(rngFindNotMand.Row, lColEnde)).Find(what:=strGrossFee, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    If .Cells(i, rngGrossFee.Column).Value Is Nothing Then
       .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    ElseIf .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Value <> .Cells(i, rngGrossFee.Column).Value Then
       .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed
           booCheck = False
    Else
       .Cells(i, rngHeader.Column).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If         
    
Next i

End With

'//Define results
Ende:

Main_Check = booCheck & “,” & Replace(CStr(rngFind.Address), “$”, “”)

If booCheck = False Then
WS.Cells(7, 7).Value = “Error counter:”
WS.Cells(7, 8).Value = WS.Cells(7, 8).Value + 1
Else
WS.Cells(7, 7).Value = “Check ok”
WS.Cells(7, 8).Value = “”
End If

WB.Close (True)

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With

Exit Function

'//If there are other errors, it should exit here and return ERROR
ErrorHandler:
On Error GoTo -1
On Error Resume Next
Main_Check = “ERROR”
WB.Close (True)

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Does this code compile/run ? There seems to be  a `Next iNotMand` line missing, Also `iCoi = rngHeader.Column`, should `iCoi` be `iCol` ? `iCoi` is undefined and not used anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you refactor your code into 3 parts. 1- read the settings, 2- profile the sheet and then 3- check the data. Debug each step in turn.

```vb
Function Main_Check2(ByVal StrFilePath As String) As String

    Const CHECK = "Check_file"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, arHdr
    Dim booCheck As Boolean, bExists As Boolean
    Dim iColFee As Long, i As Long, msg As String
    
     ' check valid filepath
    If Dir(StrFilePath) = "" Then
        msg = "'" & StrFilePath & "' does not exist"
        MsgBox msg, vbCritical, "File not found"
        Main_Check2 = msg
        Exit Function
    End If
    
     ' open file and check sheet exists
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(StrFilePath)
    bExists = False
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name = CHECK Then
            bExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If Not bExists Then
        msg = "Sheet '" & CHECK & "' not found in " & wb.FullName
        MsgBox msg, vbCritical, "Sheet not found"
        wb.Close False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' get header details from settings sheet
    Call GetSettings(Settings, arHdr)
    
    ' check headers, find fee column
    booCheck = CheckHeaders(ws, arHdr, iColFee)
    'Call DumpArray(arHdr) ' check results so far
    
    ' exit if false
    If booCheck = False Then
         Main_Check2 = booCheck
         Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' check data
    With ws
                
        '//All line items are run through and the individual criteria are checked
        Dim rngData As Range, sName As String, n As Long
        Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long, lastrow As Long, cell As Range
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(arHdr)
        
            sName = arHdr(i, 1) ' header name
            iCol = arHdr(i, 4) ' header column
            iRow = arHdr(i, 5) ' header row
            n = arHdr(i, 6) ' number of rows
            
            ' scan column
            If iCol > 0 And n > 0 Then
                Set rngData = .Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).Resize(n)
                Select Case sName
                    Case "Company"
                        For Each cell In rngData
                            If cell.Value Like "####" Then
                               cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                            Else
                               cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                               booCheck = False
                            End If
                        Next
                    
                    Case "Fee"
                        For Each cell In rngData
                            If Not cell.Value Like "*,*" Then
                               cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                            Else
                               cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                               booCheck = False
                            End If
                        Next
                                    
                    Case "Gross Fee"
                        ' optional - skipped if icol = 0
                        For Each cell In rngData
                            If Len(cell) = 0 Then
                                cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                            ElseIf cell.Value <> .Cells(cell.Row, iColFee).Value Then
                                cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                                booCheck = False
                            Else
                                cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                            End If
                        Next
                End Select
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
'//Define results
Ende:
    If booCheck = False Then
        ws.Cells(7, 7).Value = "Error counter:"
        ws.Cells(7, 8).Value = ws.Cells(7, 8).Value + 1
    Else
        ws.Cells(7, 7).Value = "Check ok"""
        ws.Cells(7, 8).Value = ""
    End If

    'wb.Close True
    Main_Check2 = booCheck '& "," & Replace(CStr(rngFind.Address), "$", "")

End Function

Function GetSettings(ws, ByRef arHdr) As Boolean

    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, r3 As Long, r4 As Long
    Dim n As Long, m As Long, i As Long, msg As String
    
    With ws
        r1 = .Range("Header_Start").Row
        r2 = .Range("Header_Ende").Row
        r3 = .Range("NotMand_Start").Row
        r4 = .Range("NotMand_Ende").Row
       
        m = r2 - r1 - 1 ' mandatory header
        n = r4 - r3 - 1 ' non-mandatory headers
       
        If m < 1 Then
            msg = "No mandatory headers on setting"
            MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, "Settings Error"
            getSettings = False
        End If
       
        ' size array and fill
        ReDim arHdr(1 To n + m, 1 To 6)
        For i = 1 To m
            arHdr(i, 1) = .Cells(r1 + i, 1)
            arHdr(i, 2) = .Cells(r1 + i, 2) ' search term
            If Len(arHdr(i, 2)) > 0 Then ' skip blanks
                arHdr(i, 3) = True ' mandatory
            Else
                arHdr(i, 3) = False
            End If
        Next
        For i = 1 To n
            arHdr(m + i, 1) = .Cells(r3 + i, 1)
            arHdr(m + i, 2) = .Cells(r3 + i, 2)
            arHdr(m + i, 3) = False ' optional
        Next
                
    End With
    getSettings = True

End Function

Function CheckHeaders(ws, ByRef arHdr, ByRef iColFee) As Boolean

    '//Header Check
    'Checks all headers in advance to see if they are present
    'and writes the missing ones in a cell
    Dim rngTable As Range, rng As Range
    Dim msg As String, sHdr As String, sTableStart As String
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, rowHdr As Long
    Dim booCheck As Boolean
   
    ' search value for column 1 of table
    sTableStart = arHdr(1, 2)
    With ws
         '//Find the beginning of the table
        Set rngTable = .Cells.Find(what:=sTableStart, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If rngTable Is Nothing Then
            msg = "Could not find begining of table '" & sTableStart & "'"
            MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, "Error"
            CheckHeaders = False
            Exit Function
        Else
            rowHdr = rngTable.Row
        End If
    
        For i = 1 To UBound(arHdr)
            sHdr = Trim(arHdr(i, 2))
            If Len(sHdr) > 0 Then ' skip blanks
                Set rng = .Rows(rowHdr).Find(what:=sHdr, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    arHdr(i, 4) = 0
                Else
                    ' store fee column for later gross fee check
                    If arHdr(i, 1) = "Fee" Then iColFee = rng.Column
                    arHdr(i, 4) = rng.Column
                    arHdr(i, 5) = rng.Row
                    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                    arHdr(i, 6) = lastrow - rng.Row - 1 ' data rows
                End If
            Else
                arHdr(i, 4) = 0
            End If
        Next
        
        ' check for mandatory column errors
        Dim sep As String
        For i = 1 To UBound(arHdr)
            If arHdr(i, 3) And arHdr(i, 4) = 0 Then
                msg = msg & sep & arHdr(i, 2)
                sep = ","
            End If
        Next

        If Len(msg) > 0 Then
            .Cells(4, 7) = "The following column labels were not found: "
            .Cells(4, 8) = msg
            .Cells(4, 8).Interior.Color = vbRed
            CheckHeaders = False
            'GoTo Ende
        Else
            .Cells(4, 7).Clear ' G4
            .Cells(4, 8).Clear ' H4
            CheckHeaders = True
        End If
    End With

End Function

' dump array to new workbook to  debug
Sub DumpArray(ar)
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    With wb.Sheets(1)
       .Name = "arHdr"
       .Range("A1:F1") = Array("Header1", "Header2", "Mandatory", "Column", "Row", "DataRows")
       .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(ar), UBound(ar, 2)) = ar
    End With
    ' save - replace existing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs "debug_arHdr.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'wb.Close
End Sub
```